# How to change the href (url) in a link (a) element?

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex, string

Here is my full link.

```
<a href="http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/">Client Portal</a>
```

I want above link to look like following.

```
<a href="#popup">Client Portal</a>
```

I really don't know how to work with preg_replace to get this done.

```
preg_replace('\/localhost\/mysite\/client-portal\/', '#popup', $output)
```

Comment: `str_replace()` will work fine. no regular expression needed

Comment: Can you please show an example?

Comment: [the manual has many examples](http://php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If is only this link you can achieve your goal with `str_replace()`:

```
<?php

$link = '<a href="http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/">Client Portal</a>';
$href = 'http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/';
$new_href = '#popup';

$new_link = str_replace($href, $new_href, $link);

echo $new_link;

?>
```

Output:

```
<a href="#popup">Client Portal</a>
```

> If you want you can use **DOM**:

```
<?php

$link = '<a href="http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/">Client Portal</a>';
$new_href = '#popup';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($link);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
   $link->setAttribute('href', $new_href);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();

?>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><a href="#popup">Client Portal</a></body></html>
```

> Or you can use `preg_replace()` like this:

```
<?php

$link = '<a href="http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/">Client Portal</a>';
$new_href = '#popup';

$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
$regex .= "(localhost)"; // Host or IP
$regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path

$pattern = "/$regex/";

$newContent = preg_replace($pattern, $new_href, $link);
echo $newContent;

?>
```

Output:

```
<a href="#popup">Client Portal</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but i have already done this as "Dagon" said above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can do using jQuery also.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<a class="popupClass" href="http://localhost/mysite/client-portal/">Client Portal</a>

$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.popupClass').attr('href','').attr('href','#popup');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p8x5wxw/1/)